# Render pages in Collection as if they were rendered by wiki engine

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am experimenting with Mediawiki [Collection extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Collection), for generating books from my articles (which I find *very* useful). However it doesn't render everything in the same way my mediawiki instance does.

Namely,

- mathjax elements don't render
- and pictures don't render as well

For instance, here how things get rendered by wiki
[image]

And how they end up in the pdf generated by Collection
[image]

I understand the reasons behind this behavior: the rendering is done not by my wiki, but by some external service, which has no idea about my client-side plugins.

My question is: how can I get my wiki render all the pages I want, possibly in HTML with all client-side extensions, and then convert the results to PDF?

When I open a page in "printable" view (with `&printable=yes`) it renders everything as I want. It could be nice to use that to render multiple pages at once (this is in essence what Collections does...)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up creating an extension that takes a list of pages and renders them all to a single page. After that I can just print it

The code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/alexeygrigorev/8124103)

This is how it looks like in PDF now:

[image]

Also you can add `&printable=yes` and it will give you a fully prepared printable version which you can just save as HTML.